# How to have a NavigationLink with swipeActions in a List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Consider a List inside of a NavigationView like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Shovel")
                Text("Bucket")
                Text("Sieve")
            
            }.navigationTitle("Sandbox")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add `.swipeActions` to the trailing edge of the list entries like so:

```
Text("Shovel")
    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
        Button{} label: { Image(systemName: "trash.fill") }
    }
```

[image: SwipeAction]

But once I embed the list entry inside of a `NavigationLink`, the `.swipeActions` don't work anymore.

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Shovel")) {
    Text("Shovel")
        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
            Button{} label: { Image(systemName: "trash.fill") }
        }
}
```

[image: NavigationLink]

Now onto the question:

#### Why is that and how can I have both of these features?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `SwipeAction` to the `NavigationLink` like so:

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Shovel")) {
    Text("Shovel")
}.swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
    Button{} label: { Image(systemName: "trash.fill") }
}
```

This behavior happens because the swipe action is a `modifier` meant for a `List Row`. When you had only `Text`, it was the row.

However, When Embedding your content in any `View` (`VStack`, `HStack`, `NavigationLink`...), that parent becomes the `Row`.